# Connection-route of node.js taking wrong parameters informations

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've a problem with my node.js application.
I'm using the packages **connection**, **connection-route**, **socket.io** and **ejs**.

My application provides informations to the html page (connected via socket.io), these informations are managed by an ejs template.
When I reach a destination with a parameter, like `http://localhost:5001/machine/:id2`, something strange happens.
The connection route code is the following:

```
router.get('/machine/:mac_id', function (req, res, next) {
    var mac_index = req.params.mac_id.slice(1,req.params.mac_id.length);
    console.log(mac_index);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    var str = mod_fs.readFileSync(mac_route + '/index.html', 'utf8') ;
    var ret = mod_ejs.render(str, { 
        filename: mac_route,
        title: "Machine Overview",
        /* other informations */
    });
    res.end(ret);
}
```

The variable `mac_route` contains the path to the file `index.html`, which is loaded correctly.
The problem lies in the `mac_index` variable. On the console are printed 3 rows:

```
id2
unctions.js
query-1.9.1.js
```

The first row is obviously correct, the last 2 rows are obviously not correct, infact these are two javascript files (my file `functions.js` and the file for jquery `jquery-1.9.1.js`).
These files are included in the header of the index.html file.

HTML STRUCTURE:

**header.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> <%= title %> </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css' type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://localhost:5001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="header">
            ...
        </div>
        <div id="page">
```

**index.html**

```
<% include /header.html %>
<div id="commands">
    ...
</div>
<div id="main">
    ... code of the page, manage informations received ...
</div>
<% include /footer.html %>
```

**footer.html**

```
        <div id="footer">
            ...
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Close the "page" div opened in the header //-->
</body>
</html>
```

I can't find where's the mistake.
Why the file's names are taken as parameter of the `req` object?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You are slicing off the first character of the parameter so `functions.js` becomes `unctions.js`

Comment: This is correct, but why the `req` object contains the name of the .js files? This is the real problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normalized URL for those files is:

```
http://localhost:5001/machine/functions.js
http://localhost:5001/machine/jquery-1.9.1.js
```

Those match your route (`/machine/:mac_id`), so they will be handled by it.

Try including the `connect.static` middleware *before* your routes:

```
app.use(connect.static(__dirname));
```

(this assumes your Connect app is stored in the `app` variable and the JS files are in the same directory as your Node script; if not, change `__dirname` to point to the directory where the JS files are located).

Comment: The static middleware was already inserted.

The route of these files with the http address no.
Now it works, thank you so much :)

Comment: Before or after your router? That order matters. Also, does it point to the correct directory?

Comment: Before the router and yes, It points correctly infact now works fine :)